# How to read line by line from a file?inside AWK

Tags: file, awk, split, line

I would like to read line from a file and after that i want to use split command on the read file.

Any suggestion?

Comment: State you problem with some details and examples.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, this is all you need.

```
awk '{print $16 + $17}' points.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Awk reads all the lines from your data file one at time and processes each line through the list of tokens in you code.. If a token matches, then the instructions on that code line are applied to the matching line. So, Awk does most of the work for you.

Comment: `BEGIN {
cat "points.txt" | awk '{split($0, a, " ")}'
}
END{
result=a[16]+a[17]
print result
}`

its not work :\

points contain a name and numbers.. and i want that its sum a 16th and 17th numbers.. do this inside awk..

Comment: Update the question instead, please.